# How to test Kafka Template using Mockito?

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito, spring-kafka

I have a class which has a public method which calls the `kafkatemplate.send()` method as shown below.

I wrote a test case for this class method but the `kafkaTemplate` is showing as null, so how to test the kafka template and get the value for `futureKafkaResponse`

```
  public class KafkaProducerService  {

  
    @Autowired
    private KafkaTemplate<String, ShopResponse> kafkaTemplate;

    @Value("${kafka.order.response.topic}")
    private String kafkaOrderResponseTopic;


    public void sendOrderResponseToKafka(OrderResponseHeader orderResponseHeader) {
        ShopResponse shopResponse = createShopResponse(orderResponseHeader);
       
     
   ListenableFuture<SendResult<String, ShopResponse>> futureKafkaResponse = kafkaTemplate.send(kafkaOrderResponseTopic,
                    shopResponse);

       
    }
```

Comment: Hope this can help you : https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-kafka-testing. Also  no where in your code, you use `Mockito`?

Comment: Show your test code, please